# How can Kibana reporting process multiple jobs at once?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using the Kibana API to retrieve visualisations. I want to be able to post multiple jobs at once and have them all process at the same time:
[image]

As you can see currently any new reporting jobs will wait until the previous one is completed, which makes things quite slow.
I've also tried posting jobs from different elastic users, thinking there's a separate job queue for each user. However the queue seems to be global for all users, therefore if I added any jobs as a separate user to the same server as above, it will have to wait until all 7 jobs created by user 'reporting' have finished before starting to process.

Any ideas on how to make this asynchronous? Or at least a workaround to speed this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on discuss.elastic.co and this was the answer:

> There is no way to run multiple reporting jobs at the same time. This is done in order to minimize the impact of reporting on the Kibana server. You could create multiple Kibana instances and this way each instance will have it's own reporting queue, iirc.
>   Also, you can schedule the reporting jobs using watcher, this way you can run them over night and have them all available in the morning.

If Kibana is purposefully limiting itself in this aspect, I'd hoped there'd be a way to at least isolate Kibana's reporting queues as their own service. Nothing like that seems available at the moment.

Comment: Did you find any solution for achieve this feature? I am also looking for same.

Comment: I looked quite extensively and didn't find a solution for this unfortunately, however I haven't checked in a while - maybe they have some kind of a solution after a year?

Comment: They don't have any solution till now, but it's working as expected when I increased elasticsearch's nodes. But I don't know exactly how it's related to elasticsearch's nodes?

Comment: Oh ok - me neither. I was under the impression Kibana reporting was being processed entirely by itself and independent from elasticsearch